# В selenium не выбирает из списка по переменной. Что делать?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

На сайте есть вот такой код:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_field_7089">1. Какова Ваша температура?</label> 
    <span data-required-id="id_field_7089">*</span> 
    
        <select name="field_7089" class="form-control" required="" id="id_field_7089">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="404">Нормальная</option>

  <option value="405">Выше нормы</option>

</select>
    
</div>
```

Я написал код:

```
q = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('form-control')
q_click = q[0]
time.sleep(1)
select = Select(q_click).select_by_visible_text(answers[0])
q_click = q[1]
time.sleep(1)
print(answers[0])
```

Импорты:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Когда я запускаю код получаю ошибку что: `Could not locate element with visible text: Нормальная`
Он не может найти элемент по видимому тексту хотя текст правильный.

Но если код сделать таким:

```
q = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('form-control')
q_click = q[0]
time.sleep(1)
select = Select(q_click).select_by_visible_text('Нормальная')
q_click = q[1]
time.sleep(1)
print(answers[0])
```

То всё работает.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: А `print(answers[0])` печатает именно "Нормальная"? Может там пробелы какие или ещё что, или буква где-то не русская закралась.

Answer (score 0):

всё правильно! Вы ищите текст ,а не атрибут! и вообще используйте итерацию для выборки

```
    search_option = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#field_7089')))
    for num, option in enumerate(search_option.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')):
        if option.get_attribute('value') == 404:
            Select(search_option).select_by_index(num).click()
```